# RxJs repeat chain on event

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have some cold RxJs Observable that I want to refresh and fetch data again from server when some event click$ emitted.

```
let files$ = param$.pipe(
  param => http.getFolder(param),
  folder => http.getFolderFiles(folder),
  REPEAT_ON(click$)
  takeUntil(this.destroy$)
)
```

What operator should I use instead of imaginary REPEAT_ON operator?

I can achieve this using this code

```
let files$ = combineLatest(param$, click$.pipe(startsWith(undefined))).pipe(
  param => http.getFolder(param[0]),
  folder => http.getFolderFiles(folder),
  takeUntil(this.destroy$)
)
```

But It smells bad and I think combineLatest is not intendent for my usecase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with `combineLatest`, but what I think you're trying to find is `repeatWhen` operator.

```
const array$ = Observable.from(["arr1", "arr2", "arr3", "arr4"]).do(console.log);
const click$ = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click');

array$
    .repeatWhen(() => click$)
    .subscribe();
```

Here is an example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EdbPoV

Comment: The problem is combineLatest needs startWith() to actually work. So repeatWhen becomes much shorter

Comment: Example link have infinite page reload loop

Answer (score 1):

Why not this ?

```
click$.pipe(
  switchMap(() => files$)
).subscribe(res => { /* result of the chain ran again */ })
```

Comment: because it won't fetch data before first click. (click should only refresh it, not start it). You could extend your solution further with startWith() but it seems to be overengineering

Comment: Yeah but that's not the fault of this piece of code, that's the fault of your design : `files$` doesn't fetch data because you coded it like so.

Comment: No the problem is that your solution is imperative rather than functional. The last is preferred for RxJs

Comment: Please tell me more about how using `repeatWhen` is functional and not imperative. Anyway, seeing the random justification, I have no more time to loose in pointless arguments : glad you resolved your issue, see you around !